# Custom WordBreaker for SQL Server Full-text

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Does anyone have information on how to create a custom word breaker for SQL Server 2005. I'd prefer to write it in c#. I need to be able to search on terms such as 'c#', 'f#' etc but the '#' character is a word breaker in the English (UK) word breaker component and can't be changed in any other way.

I have found the following article which provides an incomplete (the IWordSink interface is missing) sample and references an article that is no longer available. This article also doesn't provide any of the thread-checking code I'd expect to see.
http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/864969-custom-wordbreaker-sql-server-full-text

Alternately, someone could point me to how to decompile the existing English word breaker 'langwrbk.dll' so I could make the little change I need the existing code?

Thanks

Kirk

Comment: Please read [Implementing a Word Breaker and Stemmer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819112(v=vs.85).aspx) and also [Snowball stemmer](http://snowball.tartarus.org/)

Comment: + https://stemmersnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technology for word breakers and stemmers is common across all the Microsoft Search products, including SQL Server Fulltext. The Search SDK is well and fully documented see [Extending the Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318649%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Windows Search Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872109%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Reverse engineering the langwrbk.dll would be against the user license you agreed on, as is very clearly stipulated that you cannot reverse engineer, decompile or disassemble the Software. Not to mention that is code signed and you wouldn't be able to 'make a little change'...

Comment: Yes, Remus you are right I shouldn't decompile/disassemble the dll for all those very good reasons. I was just frustrated when I wrote my original post.