# Why dm_fts_parser method returns different result for the same input?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please execute the query below against SQL Server.

```
SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('1980s', 1033, 0, 0)
```

The result is:

```
+--------------+
| display_term |
+--------------+
| 1980s        |
+--------------+
```

And now execute the query below against SQL Server.

```
SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('1980S', 1033, 0, 0)
```

The result is:

```
+--------------+
| display_term |
+--------------+
| 1980s        |
+--------------+
| nn1980s      |
+--------------+
```

As you can see, there is only a difference between the two queries.
In the first query, the query_string parameter is `1980s` ('s' is lowercase) and in the second query the query_string parameter is `1980S` ('s' is uppercase).

### Why the result for these queries is different?

My SQL Server Version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

Comment: The result is same for me.

Comment: What is your SQLServer version?

Comment: My SQL Server version is 2014.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. The result is same here too on `MSSQL Server 2016 (SP2)`

Comment: As I found it is caused by word breaker in the SQL Server. I ran this query `EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components @component_type = 'wordbreaker', @param = 1033; ` and my word breaker version is 14.0.4763.1000 can you give me your word breaker version?